# can we use GMDH for two or three class classiication

Tags: classification

As I read in R package GMDH a function for short term forecasting of a univariate time series by using GMDH-type neural network algorithms. Can i use it for Iris Dataset?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there two GMDH packages in R:

```
 devtools::install_github("dratewka/rGMDH")
 library(rGMDH)
 m <- rGMDH::train(x,y)
 yh <- predict(m, x)
```

and

```
 library(GMDH)
 out = fcast(data, input = 6, layer = 2, f.number = 1)
```

Both are designed for short-term forecasting and you will not be able to use them for classification.

However, by design, GMDH algorithms are very suitable for multi-variable classification. In fact, better than regression (see e.g. Section 5 in http://math.umaine.edu/~farlow/gmdh%20in%20pdf.pdf or Section 8 in 
[The Review of Problems Solvable by Algorithms of the Group Method of Data Handling (GMDH)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.2971) ). Unfortunately they have not been fully implemented in R yet.

If interested, you may be able to implement it yourself using R base classes - E.g. See the first reference above to describe the exact algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use GMDH in R for classification. You can use package GMDH2
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GMDH2/GMDH2.pdf) which provides a GMDH neural network for binary classification. If you want to perform multiclass classification then you would have to use one vs all strategy and build a classifier for every class. The code below demonstrates how to use it as a binary classifier in the iris dataset, training a model to classify virginica vs the rest.

```
library(GMDH2)

data(iris)

species <- unique(iris$Species)

virginica <- iris
virginica$Species <-ifelse(iris$Species == "virginica", 1, 0)

X <- data.matrix(virginica[,1:4])
y <- virginica$Species

idx <- sample(1:nrow(X))

train_idx <- idx[1:120]
val_idx <- idx[120:150]

X_train <- X[train_idx,]
y_train <- as.factor(y[train_idx])
X_val <- X[val_idx,]
y_val <- as.factor(y[val_idx])


model_virginica <- GMDH(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val)

predict(model_virginica, X_val)
```